# No new line in repeat loop in Kotlin REPL in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

Whenever I use repeat loop in Kotlin in IntelliJ in Kotlin REPL, there is no new line after one iteration, even for the *println* statement.

```
repeat(2) {
    println("A fish is swimming")
}
```

Output:

`A fish is swimmingA fish is swimming`

But this is not the case in Kotlin Playground:

Output in Kotlin Playground:

```
A fish is swimming
A fish is swimming
```

Why are the outputs different? I could not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Kotlin IDE plugin bug, please vote and watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14979 for updates.